# About Makefile variable and shell variable

Tags: shell, makefile

```
aaa := outer
all: 
    @aaa=inner; echo ${aaa}
    @echo ${aaa}
```

I expect the output is `inner outer`, but actually is `outer outer`. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Make expands `${…}`.  If you want to pass through for the shell to expand, you need to use `$$`:

```
    @aaa=inner; echo $${aaa}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But if I the echo command is in another line, the result is empty, how to solve this problem?

Comment: see https://onecompiler.com/bash/3zhgr7dnp

Comment: Pointing to another site with a will-be-deleted example is not great on SO where this answer might be read years from now and that link is useless.  Please edit your question and put the content there.  The reason is that every logical line in a recipe is run in a _separate shell_.  So if you want _shell context_ to be available on multiple physical lines you have to turn them into a single logical line by adding backslashes (of course you also need to add another `;` and remove the `@`.

Comment: Also just to say: it's a terrible idea to add `@` to your makefiles.  At the very least you should never add them until _after_ your makefile is completely working.  If you didn't have the `@` here and you could see what make was actually invoking, perhaps it would have been more clear what the problem was.